# Javascript get width and height of img and place it into css of another class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't seem to putting the width and height of an img into another class css. If you could just give me a hint that would be nice! 
Here's my code:

```
$('.Main_hover').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var w = $this.find('img').width();
    var h = $this.find('img').height();
    $(".fusion-button-wrapper").css('height', h);
    $(".fusion-button-wrapper").css('width', w);
});
```

Of course its wrapped around a document.ready .

Here is the HTML where i want to take the width and height of the image:

```
<div class="imageframe-align-center">
  <span class="fusion-imageframe imageframe-none imageframe-1 hover-type-none Main_hover">
    <a class="fusion-no-lightbox" href="http://lowette.devel.growcreativity.be/portfolio-items/dummy3/" target="_self"> 
       <img src="http://lowette.devel.growcreativity.be/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/lowette_blok1_1.png" alt="Blok1_1" class="img-responsive">                </a>
 </span>
</div>
```

And here is the div class where i want to give the width and height:

```
<div class="fusion-button-wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Show us your HTML too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its better to do what you are doing once `img` is loaded because webkit browsers set the height and width property after the image is loaded. Which may or may not be after document ready is completed.

```js
$('.Main_hover img').load(function() {
  $(".fusion-button-wrapper").width(this.width);
  $(".fusion-button-wrapper").height(this.height);
});
```

```css
.fusion-button-wrapper{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imageframe-align-center">
  <span class="fusion-imageframe imageframe-none imageframe-1 hover-type-none Main_hover">
    <a class="fusion-no-lightbox" href="http://lowette.devel.growcreativity.be/portfolio-items/dummy3/" target="_self"> 
       <img src="http://lowette.devel.growcreativity.be/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/lowette_blok1_1.png" alt="Blok1_1" class="img-responsive">                </a>
 </span>
</div>
<div class="fusion-button-wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: The width and height does not seem to change on the class. Just tried it out, it's a wordpress site btw does this change things?

Comment: EDIT: Forgot to replace the $ for jQuery ... Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `height` `width` function of jQuery and `clientHeight` `clientWidth`
    of javascript

```
$('.Main_hover').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var h = $this.find('img')[0].clientHeight;
  var w = $this.find('img')[0].clientWidth;
  $(".fusion-button-wrapper").height(h);
  $(".fusion-button-wrapper").width(w);
});
```

Comment: Its not guaranteed that this will work. Depends on the image load time on webkit browsers.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan your correct it will work once image is loaded in the dom